# Editing already published web mapping applications

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

Is there a way to update the web mapping application on ArcGIS Online?

I have an application that I want to add layers to from our REST services and I can't seem to find a way to add it. It does not give me the option to edit the application. It gives me the options to view item details and view application.

I do not have to original web map for the application - so I wouldn't be able to republish it.  It was originally published in 2015.

Comment: Are you the owner of the application?

Comment: I am the owner of the application.